# Could not find installable ISAM in excel 2007 vba

Tags: vba, excel-2007

i want to try connecting excel to excel using ado connection and vba. but the problem is it give's an error could not find installable ISAM. i tried to look at other solution but same issue will return. may be there's a activex control that im missing? here's my code

```
Dim cN As ADODB.Connection '* Connection String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset '* Record Set
Dim sQuery As String '* Query String
Dim i1 As Long
Dim lMaxRow As Long '* Last Row in the Sheet
Dim iRevCol As Integer '*
Dim i3 As Integer

Set cN = New ADODB.Connection
cN.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Excel Programming\PlayerDatabase.xlsm;Readonly=False;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;;HDR=yes;Persist Security Info=False"
cN.ConnectionTimeout = 40
cN.Open

Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

lMaxRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
sQuery = "Select * From [Player$]"


RS.ActiveConnection = cN
RS.Source = sQuery
RS.Open

If RS.EOF = True And RS.BOF = True Then
    MsgBox ("End of File")
End If

If RS.State <> adStateClosed Then
RS.Close
End If

If Not RS Is Nothing Then Set RS = Nothing
If Not cN Is Nothing Then Set cN = Nothing
```

**UPDATE:**

now i change my connectionstring to this

```
cN.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Excel Programming\PlayerDatabase.xlsm;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES'"
```

but it gives me error Cannot update. **Database or object is readonly.**

when i put readonly=false

```
cN.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Excel Programming\PlayerDatabase.xlsm;ReadOnly=false;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES'"
```

it will give an error as could not find installable ISAM :(

Comment: Your `ConnectionString` seems to be overstated. Go to [ConnectionStrings.Com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) and check for correct syntax appropriate to the environment you work with and file(s) you get data from.

Comment: in my update issue, i took that connectionstring to the site you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is inside your `XLSM` file you retrieve data from but you connection string should be as simple as possible. This is working for me (but I didn't check for read-only parameter):

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=C:\Users\Dane\BazaDanych.xlsm;" & _
           "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Macro"
```

Comment: actually my xlsm database is still empty.. just want to check if the connnection using ado is success... do you have any idea how can i make may datase.xlsm to write/read?

Comment: do you have any example or wokbook that i can be download?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you really need... to check if ADO works you need to have some data in `PlayerDatabase.xlsm` and set everything correct including correct SQL statement. To input data to any file you will need different connection settings and different SQL statement. In your question you ask for ISAM problem therefore I've provided possible solution and ideas. For others, please as other question.

Comment: ok sorry.. yes i used your code but unfortunately it gives the database or object as readonly

Answer (score 0):

Solved it as follows:

```
string ConeectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFlp.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"");
OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection(ConeectionString);
```